# How to fix Windows Live Writer 2012 Url Names?

Tags: windows-live-writer

I have am using Blog Engine 2.8 with Windows Live Writer. I noticed when publish a post I get a url like this

```
http://www.example.com/post/2013/06/28/.aspx
```

but when I use Blog Engines post area I get a url like this

```
http://www.example.com/post/2013/07/02/test.aspx
```

so for some reason it does not put a name just the extension.

So when I try to remove extensions(setting in BE) all my windows live writer posts die as there is no name anymore.